# Error: Could not find or load main class but main method exists - command line is used

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I would like to test an client for TPC server-client. I'm using this code of server.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ServerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientSentence;
          String capitalizedSentence;
          ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

          while (true) {
           Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
           BufferedReader inFromClient =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
           DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
           clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
           System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
           try {
           capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
           outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
           } catch (Exception e){}   finally {
               
           }
          }
    }

}
```

And would like to build and run this code in command like:

> javac ServerTest.java
>
> java ServerTest.class

but the second command fails with error below:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ServerTest.class

Why?

If this code is built and run in Eclipse all works fine.

> java -version

yields this:

> java version "1.8.0_45"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

I can't find a proper solution in stackoverflow. And do not understand the core of the problem. If you can know where this behaviour explains, please, give me the url.

Comment: Try `java ServerTest` , you are not supposed to add the `.class` .

Comment: Run `java ServerTest`, not `java ServerTest.class`. The `java` command expects a class name, not a filename.

Comment: Oh. Thanks , Berger and Jesper. It works with `java ServerTest`